# what does -1 offset argument mean to uv_fs_read and uv_fs_write?

Tags: libuv

According to the official documentation at [libuv/fs](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/fs.html):

> int `uv_fs_read`(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_fs_t* req, uv_file file, const uv_buf_t bufs[], unsigned int nbufs, int64_t offset, uv_fs_cb cb)
>
> Equivalent to `preadv(2)`.

But in the man page of `preadv` there is an `EINVAL` error for negative offset argument.

However the example of [uvbook](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/filesystem.html#reading-writing-files) uses -1 offset argument to `uv_fs_write` and `uv_fs_read` and it works as what the program  is expected(cat a file).

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the code for libuv version 1.20.1, if the file offset is < 0 then read/write uses the current file position.

Specifically, unix uses the functions [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [readv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readv.2.html) depending on if there are multiple iovec values, and [write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) or [writev](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/writev.2.html) for writing.

For Windows, when the offset is less than zero then `ReadFile` is called without first calling `SetFilePointerEx` or setting the overlapped offset value.